# How can I do a call back to the code behind method using javascript (properly)?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

So I am trying to call back to a code behind method using Javascript and it seems like the only way to do so is using the

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock()
```

Method.

I don't need to return any data back to the calling javascript function.

This isn't a web service, so I am not going to use a ajax call, but this seems like there would be an easier way to do this than Client Callbacks Programmatically with Page.ClientScript.....

Comment: `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock` does not allow to call back from a javascript function to a serverside function. You'll use it to inject client script from serverside that gets called directlty when the page is loading on client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock) is just used to push some JavaScript code block in your page. This is not intended to call server method. 
If you want to call server code from JavaScript, you should check for the [`[WebMethod]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.services.webmethodattribute) attribute.  Basically, you put that attribute on top of a public static method of your page, and you can call it in JavaScript.

C# Example:

```
[WebMethod]  
public static void MyWebMethod(string foo)  
{  
    doSomething(foo);  
}
```

VB.NET Example:

```
<WebMethod> 
Public Sub MyWebMethod(foo As String)
    doSomething foo
End Function
```

And then, in JavaScript:

```
<script type="application/javascript">  
    PageMethods.MyWebMethod(someValue);  
</script>
```

And you're done.

Comment: Am not exposing this method as if it part of a webservice?

Comment: You write this method in the code-behind of your page. It works quite like a web service, but I don't think that someone could call it directly, from another site.  When the page is generated, Asp.net generates the javascript namespace that allow you to call your method with `PageMethods.MyWebMethod`.  Alternatively, you can pass a parameter to the attribute so you have access to the user's session when calling the method. Not sure if I remember correctly, but I think you just have to add `[WebMethod(true)]` in order to use the Session variable.