# Hide a Radbutton which is inside a popup when another popup form is submitted and closed upon OnClientClicking

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

I have a page "Main2.aspx" and inside this page, I have a button "Transactions" upon clicking this button opens a popup form "Transactions" and Inside this popup, I have coded a button "AddRadbutton" and Upon clicking this "AddRadbutton" on using Javascript URL redirection a new popup "SaveDetails" form will appear.

This "SaveDetails" form is having a "SaveRadButton", upon clicking this "SaveRadButton" my form details will be saved and the popup closes successfully.

The problem I'm facing here is, "AddRadbutton" on the "Transactions" form is still visible even after filling and submitting the details using "SaveRadButton" on "SaveDetails" form.

Earlier, I'm able to achieve the same scenario by coding on Server Side, when I have used the same "SaveDetails" popup page in User Control Page which is inside "Main1.aspx" but not here on Main2.aspx.

In Main2.aspx page I can only achieve this only when page refresh happens. but I need this "AddRadbutton" to be Hidden Immeadiately after submitting the form in "SaveDetails" popup form.

Techniques I've tried so far:

Below is the Code for AddRadButton (which is in Transactions popup)

```
<div id="AddDetailsDiv" runat="server" visible="true" style="width: auto; height: auto; float: left; margin-right: 10px;">
<telerik:RadButton ID="AddRadButton" runat="server" Text="Add Details" 
CausesValidation="False" TabIndex="14" OnClientClicking="showDetailsWindow" UseSubmitBehavior="false" > 
</telerik:RadButton>
</div>
```

Below is the Code for SaveRadButton (which is in SaveDetails popup)

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="SaveRadButton" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="InsertRadButton"
```

In Server Side for OnClick is there any chance of handling this issue using below line:

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "RadWindow", "CloseBind();", true);
```

I've tried coding another Javascript function and use it in `OnClientClicking` or `OnClientClicked` and call both functions but unable to achieve it because Telerik UI is not supporting or I might be missing something else.

I've tried this basic `AddRadButton.Visible = false` on server side, its working, but only after page refresh but I needed it to be hidden Immeadiately after popup form submission.

I've tried handling in the below code() but unable to achieve it.

```
 function CloseBind() {

 var oWindow = GetRadWindow();
 oWindow.close();
 oWindow.BrowserWindow.loadDetails();

 }
 function GetRadWindow() {
 var oWindow = null;
 if (window.radWindow) oWindow = window.radWindow;
 else if (window.frameElement.radWindow) oWindow = window.frameElement.radWindow;
 return oWindow;
 }
```

I've searched and tried many stackoverflow-related questions, scenarios and also on many community developer sites but those didn't help me either.

Any Ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to solve the problem by introducing an alert() before the window is closed so that the page refresh happens upon alert "OK" button click from the user side.

I've tried by calling an alert function in telerik: RadWindow using `OnClientClose="saveDetailsWindowClose"`

```
<telerik:RadWindowManager EnableShadow="true" Behaviors="Maximize, Close" ID="MainRadWindowManager"
            DestroyOnClose="false" Opacity="100" runat="server" Modal="true" AutoSize="false"
            
            CssClass="lte_colpopup" KeepInScreenBounds="true" RestrictionZoneID="MainContent"
            VisibleStatusbar="false" style="overflow: hidden !important">
            <Windows>
            <telerik:RadWindow ID="MyRadWindow" ReloadOnShow="true" ShowContentDuringLoad="false" OnClientClose="saveDetailsWindowClose"
                                Width="950" Height="450" runat="server" Title="Person Details">
            </telerik:RadWindow>
            </Windows>

</telerik:RadWindowManager>
 
<telerik:RadScriptBlock ID="MasterScriptBlock" runat="server">
```

I've used below simple Javascript function to alert the User:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function saveDetailsWindowClose(sender, args) {
                 alert('A Screen refresh is mandatory to load the details, so please click "OK" button to proceed');
                 window.location.reload();
        }
</script>

</telerik:RadScriptBlock>
```

This is how I solved the Issue, fortunately, AddRadbutton on both these Main1.aspx and Main2.aspx and also on popup pages are working as intended. Luckily it didn't hamper with the closing of a window in UserControl Page on Main1.aspx which is using the same saveDetails.aspx page.

Answer (score 1):

```
AddRadButton.Visible = false
```

should work. You will need to make sure that it's inside an `if` which checks for `IsPostback`. If that does not work for you, then it's possible that a later event in the [WebForms lifecycle](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8911c4/page-life-cycle-with-examples-in-Asp-Net/) `overrides` it, maybe a render-related event is where this should be implemented, like OnPreRender. You could also register a callback script (see [How can I do a call back to the code behind method using javascript (properly)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264642/how-can-i-do-a-call-back-to-the-code-behind-method-using-javascript-properly)) and invoke a Javascript functions that changes the `display` styling to none.

Comment: Thankyou @Lajos Arpad , I've tried using AddRadButton.Visible = false in IsPostback but it's working only after manual refresh from user side until then the button is visible. I've also tried to use the Life Cycle Event you have suggested and some other things which didn't work out form me. I've also tried to do Call back to the server-side code by using javascript but it's acting weird and it didn't help either. So finally I came up with the solution of introducing an alert() to the Radwindow local to that Page on Main2.aspx without hampering Main1.aspx.